# Vectorizing the kriging estimator in R

Tags: r, performance, vectorization

I am writing some code to run a Gaussian Process from a Bayesian point of view, and I want to estimate my parameters in a loop and then also obtain the kriging estimator within the loop as well.  The problem that I am running in to is that I have to run a double for-loop in R which can be notoriously slow.  I am trying to figure out how to speed up the computations (tried writing the kriging estimator as a function then passing it to the apply function inside teh loop) but it is still painfully slow.  Was hoping someone might be able to lend some guidance on how to vectorize my problem or any other tricks that may speed up the code.  Here is the code I wrote:

```
#Example Data and function
x = sort(runif(4,0,1))
y = exp(-1.4*x)*cos(7*pi*x/2)

#Distance matrix
tau = as.matrix(dist(x,upper=T,diag=T))

#Correlation Matrix
corrR = function(psi,tau){
    R = exp(-tau^(1.99)*psi)
    return(R)
}

#Full conditional for psi
psi.cond = function(psi,r,sig,D,beta,Y){
    d = .01
    e = .01
    ans = det(r)^(-.5)*exp(-.5/sig*t(Y-D*beta)%*%solve(r)%*%(Y-D*beta))*psi^-(d+1)*exp(-e/psi)
    #ans = -.5*log(det(r))-.5/sig*t(Y-D*beta)%*%solve(r)%*%(Y-D*beta)-(d+1)*log(psi)-e/psi
    return(as.real(ans))
}

#Kriging estimator
krig = function(x.new,x,beta,psi,tau,Y,D){

    S = length(x.new)
    pred = rep(NA,S)
    for(j in 1:S){

        R = corrR(psi,tau)

        r = as.matrix(dist(c(x,x.new[j]),upper=T,diag=T))[(length(x)+1):(length(x)+length(x.new[j])),1:length(x)]
        r = t(as.matrix(exp(-psi*r^(1.99)),nrow=nrow(r),ncol=length(x)))

        pred[j] = as.real(beta+r%*%solve(R)%*%(Y-D*beta))
}
    return(pred)

}

D = rep(1,length(x))
Y = as.matrix(y)

m = length(x)
a = 2
b = 1

#Number of MCMC iterations = B
B = 50000
beta = c(1,rep(NA,B))
sigma = rep(NA,B) 
psi = c(120,rep(NA,B-1))

#Number of predicted points = S
S = 100
yhat = matrix(NA,nrow=B,ncol=S)
x.new = as.matrix(seq(0,1,len=S))

for(i in 1:B){

    R = corrR(psi[i],tau)
    bhat = as.real(solve(t(D)%*%solve(R)%*%D)%*%t(D)%*%solve(R)%*%Y)

    sigma[i] = 1/rgamma(1,(m+2*a)/2,(as.real(t(Y-D*beta[i])%*%solve(R)%*%(Y-D*beta[i]))+2*b)/2)
    beta[i+1] = rnorm(1,bhat,t(D)%*%solve(sigma[i]*R)%*%D)

    log.xi = rnorm(1,log(psi[i]),.1)
    xi = exp(log.xi)

    u = runif(1)

    R.xi = corrR(xi,tau)
    R.psi = corrR(psi[i],tau)

    temp = (psi.cond(xi,R.xi,sigma[i],D,beta[i],Y)*(1/psi[i]))/(psi.cond(psi[i],R.psi,sigma[i],D,beta[i],Y)*(1/xi))
    alpha = min(1,temp)

    if(u <= alpha){
        psi[i+1] = xi
    }else{
        psi[i+1] = psi[i]
    }

    yhat[i,] = apply(x.new,1,krig,x=x,beta=beta[i+1],psi=psi[i+1],tau,Y,D)

}
```

Comment: Should this be migrated to [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that any function can be vectorised with `Vectorize`:

```
krig <- Vectorize(krig, vectorize.args="x")
```

The long answer is that this is just a wrapper for `mapply`, and won't really help in your case where most of the compute time is taken up by humongous matrix algebra.

You could rewrite the number-crunching bits in C, C++ or Fortran, and that would probably give you a much greater speedup than removing the outer loops. You could also consider whether the algorithm you're using is naive and look for better alternatives. (Per `?det`: "Often, computing the determinant is not what you should be doing to solve a given problem." The same applies for single-argument `solve`.)

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  If I wanted to speed up the code using C how would I go about that?

Answer (score 1):

Some basic points...

`kriging` will at some point involve inverting matrices. There is no point in inverting the same matrix 
multiple times.

Looking at these two lines of code you invert `R` 3 times -- obviously you could save some time by defining the inverse of R once and then reusing

```
bhat = as.real(solve(t(D)%*%solve(R)%*%D)%*%t(D)%*%solve(R)%*%Y)

sigma[i] = 1/rgamma(1,(m+2*a)/2,(as.real(t(Y-D*beta[i])%*%solve(R)%*%(Y-D*beta[i]))+2*b)/2)
beta[i+1] = rnorm(1,bhat,t(D)%*%solve(sigma[i]*R)%*%D)
```

Furthermore functions such as `crossprod` and `tcrossprod` exist that are usually faster than the direct  calls to `t(x) %*% y` or `x %*%t(y)`

If you look at the [`geoR package`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/geoR/index.html), (which implements  traditional, Likelihood and Bayesian approaches to geostatistical analysis, most of the work within `krige.conv` is performed  in this way.

You may find that `geoR::krige.bayes` provides all the functionality you want (and is reasonably fast). `krige.bayes` uses a number of `C` functions to perform the appropriate simulations.

You could look at the [`geoRExtended package`](http://widatagetter.r-forge.r-project.org/#geoRExtended) which is a partial rewrite of `geoR` using `RcppArmadillo` to implement most of the matrix manipulations required.

The [`gstat` package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gstat/index.html) does not implement Bayesian approach, but is awesomely fast for kriging (the workhorse `predict.gstat` calls a `C` function).